# reemplazar un valor de una columna eloquent laravel

Tags: php, sql, laravel, eloquent

De que forma puedo hacer un replace de un valor que viene en una columna, por ejemplo tengo la columna DocTotal, esta tiene un valor de 125000.000000 y quiero eliminar los 6 cero y el punto... tengo algo asi como idea pero no me funciona o mas bien no logro la query correctamente!

en base a algunos ejemplos que vi, entiendo que seria:

replace('lacolumnadebasededatos', 'lo que deseo reemplazar', 'por que lo deseo reemplazar')
o estoy equivocado?

```
$pendientesdepago = PendienteDePagos::where('LicTradNum', '<>', '12345678-1')
                                    ->where('PaidSum', '=', '.000000')
                                    ->whereRaw("REPLACE('DocTotal', '.000000', '')")->get();
```

Comment: el replace deberia ir en la parte donde haces la seleccion de los campos, no en el where, porque se estaria interpretando como whereRaw("125000")

Comment: Algo asi ```->selectRaw("REPLACE('DocTotal', '.000000', '')")``` esto es una respuesta clara de la siguiente pregunta parecida https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56602155/use-replace-function-with-laravel-database-query-builder

Comment: ¿Qué tipo de dato es `DocTotal`?

Answer (score 1):

la forma correcto de hacerlo es con un update, anteriormente tuve ese problema y lo solucione de esta forma, aqui un ejemplo:

```
PendienteDePagos::where('LicTradNum', '<>', '12345678-1')
   ->where('PaidSum', '=', '.000000')
   ->update([
      'DocTotal' =>  DB::raw("REPLACE(DocTotal, '000000', '')")
   ]);
```

Comment: se ve interesante eso bro... lo malo aca es que la data lamentablemente me la estan entregando bien feita hahaha gracias por el codigo y compartir amigo, saludos!

Answer (score 0):

lo he resuelto simplemente en la blade.php
quitando los cero y el punto, luego pasando a formato number...

dejo la solucion por si a alquien le sirve en algun momento.

```
<td>$ {{ number_format(str_replace('.000000', '', $item->DocTotal), 0, ',', '.') }}</td>
```